# How can I dynamically change title bar title in the android application?

Tags: android, titlebar

I want to change the title in the title bar dynamically.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use setTitle(title string ); to change the text of the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the title in the title bar dynamically you should use :

```
setTitle("your string");
```